# How to create a new google meet using google calendar api

Tags: reactjs, api, google-chrome, google-calendar-api

I need implement a javascript project that creates a new google meet according to the user signed in and adds the event to the calendar and gets the url of the google meet. How can i create a new google meet using Google Calendar API in JS.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You need to use the `conferenceData.createRequest` parameter of the Events resource when creating a Calendar.Events: insert request to add a Meet link to a Calendar Event.*

#### More Information:

As per the documention for [Events: insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) and the [Event resource reperesentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource):

> **`conferenceDataVersion`:** `integer`
>
> > Version number of conference data supported by the API client. Version 0 assumes no conference data support and ignores conference data in the event's body. Version 1 enables support for copying of ConferenceData as well as for creating new conferences using the createRequest field of conferenceData. The default is 0. Acceptable values are `0` to `1`, inclusive.
>
> ---
>
> **`conferenceData.createRequest`:** `nested object`
>
> > A request to generate a new conference and attach it to the event. The data is generated asynchronously. To see whether the data is present check the `status` field.
> >
> > Either `conferenceSolution` and at least one `entryPoint`, or `createRequest` is required.
>
> ---
>
> **`conferenceData.createRequest.conferenceSolutionKey.type`:** `string`
>
> > The conference solution type.
> >
> > If a client encounters an unfamiliar or empty type, it should still be able to display the entry points. However, it should disallow modifications.
> >
> > The possible values are:
> >
> > - "`eventHangout`" for Hangouts for consumers (http://hangouts.google.com)
> > - "`eventNamedHangout`" for classic Hangouts for G Suite users (http://hangouts.google.com)
> > - "`hangoutsMeet`" for Google Meet (http://meet.google.com)
> > - "`addOn`" for 3P conference providers
>
> ---
>
> **`conferenceData.createRequest.requestId`:** `string`
>
> > The client-generated unique ID for this request.
> > Clients should regenerate this ID for every new request. If an ID provided is the same as for the previous request, the request is ignored.

With this information we can generate a Calendar Event creation request with a Meet link as the conference solution.

#### Example Request:

```
gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
  "calendarId": "primary",
  "conferenceDataVersion": 1,
  "resource": {
    "end": {
      "date": "2020-10-24"
    },
    "start": {
      "date": "2020-10-23"
    },
    "conferenceData": {
      "createRequest": {
        "conferenceSolutionKey": {
          "type": "hangoutsMeet"
        },
        "requestId": "some-random-string"
      }
    },
    "summary": "titles are cool"
  }
});
```

**NB:** In order for a Meet link to be generated, you ***must*** set `conferenceData.createRequest.requestId` to ***any random string***. For each new meet link you wish to create, you must use a ***different string*** in the request.

#### References:

- [Events: insert | Calendar API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert)
- [Events | Calendar API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events)

Comment: Thank you very much, how can i connect my app so that makes requests to calendar api. I am referring to [https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/js](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/js) and trying to connect to api but it's showing  **This app isn't verified
This app hasn't been verified by Google yet. Only proceed if you know and trust the developer.**

Comment: @VishnuDarshan You have to have your app verified if this is the case. Completing the OAuth consent screen on [console.cloud.google.com](https://console.cloud.google.com) for your project is the direction to go for this. You can use the app anyway, there should be an button which says something like 'I am aware of the risks'

Comment: I tried doing that , i clicked on the Advanced option and it is showing like **Google hasn't reviewed this app yet and can't confirm it's authentic. Unverified apps may pose a threat to your personal data. Learn more

Go to Quickstart (unsafe)**. Is verifying the only way to by pass this ?.

Comment: I tried verifying my app, went to the OAuth consent screen and it is showing like **Verification Status
Verification not required
Your consent screen is being shown, but your app has not been reviewed so your users may not see all of your information, and you will not be able to request certain OAuth scopes. Learn more**. Can you help me regarding this verification process, please.

Comment: Check out the Google links for verification [here](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en) and [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification). There's not really much more that people on stack can help you with regarding this though - if you are having project-specific issues with verification the best thing you can go is contact Google Workplace support - the details for this are [on this help page](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en)

Comment: I am creating hangoutsMeet type of conference using G-suite, now Google Workspace account. Meeting is created, but no one can join. It is waiting for organizer to confim invitation, but who is organizer? Calendar is set, so when new event is created in calendar, it adds meet automatically. Any idea? When using my gmail account I can connect.

Answer (score 11):

If you aren't using the node library, the request with `axios` is below. I did not realize from the answer above `conferenceDataVersion` is a query param.

```
let event = {
    summary: "some text",
    location: "some text",
    description: "some text",
    start: {
      dateTime: start,
      timeZone: timeZone,
    },
    end: {
      dateTime: end,
      timeZone: timeZone,
    },
    recurrence: [],
    attendees: [
      { email: 'johndoe@whatever.com' }, 

    ],
    reminders: {
      useDefault: true,
    },
    conferenceData: {
      createRequest: {
        conferenceSolutionKey: {
          type: 'hangoutsMeet',
        },
        requestId: 'somerequestid',
      },
    },
  };
  
const createEventRequest = await axios({
    url: `https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/${calendarId}/events?conferenceDataVersion=1`,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    },
    data: event,
  });
```

Comment: Extremely valuable comment. It's the same when using the googleapis npm package.

Answer (score 4):

Extending @Brit's comment in googleapis npm package the way it should be executed will be

```js
let response = await calendar.events.insert({
    auth: auth,
        calendarId: calendarId,
        resource: event,
        conferenceDataVersion: 1
    });
```

with `event` as

```js
let event = {
    'summary': `Appointment.`,
    'description': `Description`,
    'start': {
        'dateTime': dateTime['start'],
        'timeZone': 'Asia/Kolkata'
    },
    'end': {
        'dateTime': dateTime['end'],
        'timeZone': 'Asia/Kolkata'
    },
    'attendees': [
        {'email': '...@gmail.com'},
    ],
    'reminders': {
        'useDefault': false,
        'overrides': [
          {'method': 'email', 'minutes': 24 * 60},
          {'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 10},
        ],
    },
    "conferenceData": {
        "createRequest": {
            "conferenceSolutionKey": {
                "type": "hangoutsMeet"
            },
            "requestId": "JksKJJSK1KJSK"
        }
    },
    
};
```