# How to get HangoutLink from Event created in Google Calendar API in C#?

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to create an event like this way:

```
calendarEvent.ConferenceData = new ConferenceData
               {
                   ConferenceSolution = new ConferenceSolution
                   {
                       Key = new ConferenceSolutionKey
                       {
                           Type = "hangoutsMeet"
                       }
                   },
                   CreateRequest = new CreateConferenceRequest
                   {
                       RequestId = "qwsdimop",                         
                       ConferenceSolutionKey = new ConferenceSolutionKey
                       {
                           Type = "hangoutsMeet"
                       }
                   }
                   ,
                   EntryPoints = new List<EntryPoint>
                   {
                       new EntryPoint
                       {
                           EntryPointType = "video",
                       }
                   }
               };
```

I set the `ConferenceDataVersion` to this way:

```
               EventsResource.InsertRequest request = service.Events.Insert(calendarEvent, "example@gmail.com");
               request.ConferenceDataVersion = 1;
```

But I get and Error: *Invalid conference type value*

when I run the code without this line:

```
ConferenceSolutionKey = new ConferenceSolutionKey
                       {
                           Type = "hangoutsMeet"
                       }
```

the event is created correctly but doesn't get the hangoutlink

Does anyone know why that happens or how to do it the right way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64539847/how-to-create-a-new-google-meet-using-google-calendar-api

Comment: No :(, I just tried but I keep getting the same error *Invalid conference type value*, is it not because I use a gmail account through a service account?

Comment: Can you copy the full request body you are making as if you where using the API explorer? https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert?apix=true