# Flutter App + Google Calendar API : events.insert not returning 'conferenceData'

Tags: flutter, google-calendar-api

I am following [this github code](https://github.com/sbis04/events_demo) as an example to create a google calendar event in a workspace calendar using a service account.

I followed various examples on how to authenticate and connect using a service account and now I am able to create an event and it shows up in the workspace calendar as well successfully.

However, the event that is returned does not have the 'conferenceData' from which I could fetch the 'conferenceId' to create the google meet link.

Below is the insert code that I use, which works but does not return the said conference data.

```
       await calendar.events.insert(event, calendarId,
              conferenceDataVersion: 1, sendUpdates: "none")
          .then((value) {
            print("Event Status: ${value.status}");
            if (value.status == "confirmed") {
              print(value.toJson().toString());
              String joiningLink;
              String eventId;

              eventId = value.id; 
              joiningLink = "https://meet.google.com/${value.conferenceData?.conferenceId}";
            
              print('Event added to Google Calendar : $joiningLink');
            }
           }
          });
```

Here's the output I get printed to the console:

```
I/flutter ( 2934): Event Status: confirmed
I/flutter ( 2934): {created: 2022-07-26T16:12:20.000Z, creator: Instance of 'EventCreator', description: xxxx-desc, end: Instance of 'EventDateTime', etag: "3317703881666000", eventType: default, htmlLink: https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=djc1b2gyY3RzZ2p1YWGo4aWtmdWIydG5pZ3R2aGNvNEBn, iCalUID: v75oh2ctsgjuahtircv@google.com, id: v75oh2ctv7itndnc, kind: calendar#event, location: Google Meet, organizer: Instance of 'EventOrganizer', reminders: Instance of 'EventReminders', sequence: 0, start: Instance of 'EventDateTime', status: confirmed, summary: xxxxxxx, updated: 2022-07-26T16:12:20.833Z}
I/flutter ( 2934): Event added to Google Calendar : https://meet.google.com/null
```

Any suggestions on how to get the conferenceData and hence the conferenceId?

*** EDIT ****

Something else turned up while I was digging around:

While it doesn't matter for my use case, but google api won't allow me to add attendees - even if it is the service account email id.

> Error creating event DetailedApiRequestError(status: 403, message:
> Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide
> Delegation of Authority.)

I don't understand, domain-wide delegation is already done for this account and that is why I am able to authenticate and create a calendar event in the first place.

Is my understanding wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64540729/19602805) that could get you in the right direction. You need to add the `conferenceData.createRequest` values in the `insert()` method in order to get a Google Meet link from the new event.

About the error related to Domain-Wide Delegation:

It is expected to get this error when the service account is not impersonating any user in the Google Workspace organization, you can review [this section](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests) from Google Developers under "Delegate domain wide authority" and try to update the code in order to impersonate a different user. Looking around I found [here](https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis_auth#impersonation) that the optional argument that you could when using a service account in your case is `impersonatedUser`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. At least I got one response! However, I am already doing this in the insert() method. I'm adding it to 'event' like:

calendarapi.ConferenceData conferenceData = calendarapi.ConferenceData();
calendarapi.CreateConferenceRequest conferenceRequest = calendarapi.CreateConferenceRequest();
conferenceRequest.requestId = "${startTime.millisecondsSinceEpoch}-${endTime.millisecondsSinceEpoch}";
conferenceData.createRequest = conferenceRequest;
event.conferenceData = conferenceData;

Any other suggestions?